# how to parse results of joint query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list, object, join

In my project I have 2 beans (Demande & Candidat ), and  I want to execute a join query with Hibernate like this:

```
String squery="select d.date_demande, c.nom, c.prénom from Demande d , Candidat c where d.id_candidat=c.id_candidat";
SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery(squery);
```

The issue is that I don't know which object this query returns. I want to put the result of this query in a list so I can use it in a jsp file easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String squery="select date_demande as {d.date_demande},nom as {c.nom}, prénom as {c.prénom} from Demande d , Candidat c   
                where d.id_candidat=c.id_candidat";
SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery(squery);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
Map<String,Object> row = null;
List data = query.list();
for (Object object : data) {
     row= (Map<String,Object>)object;
     System.out.println("date_demande: " + row.get("date_demande"));
     System.out.println("nom: " + row.get("nom"));
     System.out.println("prénom: " + row.get("prénom"));
}
```

Please ensure List data = query.list(); returning results.

**update**

Iterate the map and see the values and keys and work based on that.

```
for (Object object : data) {

      Map row = (Map) object;
      Iterator entries = row.entrySet().iterator();
      while (entries.hasNext()) {
           Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
           System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
     }
 }
```

or

```
   for (Object object : data) {

      Map row = (Map) object;
      System.out.print(row.get("0"));
      System.out.print("\t" + row.get("1"));
      System.out.print("\t" + row.get("2"));

   }
```

Write this in your servlet/struts/spring controller

```
  request.setAttribute("list", data);
```

Write this in your jsp

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="map">
       <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
              ${entry.key}<br>
              ${entry.value}<br>
       </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: it returns null values , and the table in my database is not empty, even with a simple query like "select date_demande from Demande " it gives me null values .. 
Thank you for your answer btw !

Comment: Yes it's returning results (data.size() =16) it means it gets values but still having null as a result , i guess the problem is in row.get("....")

Comment: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/handling-unknown-object-in-arraylist.html see the reference

Comment: And Please how can i get this List to show it in a table with jstl code ? should i return the data list ?

Comment: Can u post the  output here. System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

Comment: Key = Date_demande, Value = 25/08/2013 22:09:04
Key = Nom_candidat, Value = test
Key = Id_candidat, Value = 2

What i want to do is to use this list of values to fill a table in my jsp page , a table that contains columns (id_candidat , nom_candidat , date_demande) .

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember at this time, but I think it should be sth like that:

"select d.date_demande, c.nom, c.prenom from Demande as d inner join Candidat as c"

If you have correctly defined model (pk's addnotations and relations) it joins automaticly by id.

There is some about joins in hql
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

If I helped you, please vote that ;)